# Django reverse ORM join queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want all the rows of my (MovieMaster table) for which (SetMovie table) exists. These are my models

```
 class MovieMaster(models.Model):
       m_name = models.CharField('Movie Name',max_length=50)
       m_desc = models.CharField('Movie Description', max_length=50)
       m_image = models.ImageField('Movie Image',upload_to="pics/")

       def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("admin_side:addmovie")

       def __str__(self):
            return self.m_name


 class SetMovie(models.Model):
      active = models.ForeignKey(MovieMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      show = models.CharField('Show Time', max_length=50)
      start_time = models.DateField()
      end_time = models.DateField()

      def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse("admin_side:setmovie")
```

Basically I want to execute this sql query (SELECT * from MovieMaster INNER JOIN SetMovie ON MovieMaster.id = SetMovie.id). I am new at this. I am able to get all SetMovie row for MovieMaster by using

```
  models.SetMovie.objects.select_related('active')
```

But I am not able to get all values of MovieMaster table for SetMovie table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 MovieMaster.objects.filter(setmovie__isnull=False)
```